# Все обращения на index - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

Вот мой htaccess, предельно простой. По идее должен пускать все обращения на индекс, но получается так, что урлы типа example.test/example падают в 404, работает только example.test/.
Может я тупой, конечно, но уже порылся а инете и ничего не нашел.

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете или не всё показали. Например у вас работает маршрутизация, которая тут не указана

Comment: Вы перезапускали апач? Вы уверены, что записали правило в нужном хосте? Вы уверены, что .htaccess разрешён для обработки в данном хосте?

Answer (score 0):

1. Убедитесь, что файл index.php существует
2. Убедитесь, что папки или файла с именем example не существует
3. Убедитесь, что 404 страница не генерируется внутри php кода, для этого временно удалите все из index.php, оставив тестовый код типа `echo 'Hello World';`

По результатам этих действий можно будет предположить в чем причина 404-й